# Can i control emission brightness using an object controller with animation nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like these pipes to gradually light up when the ball floats over them but i cant work out how to get each pipe to work independently of each other. At the moment the brightness is dictated by how close the ball is to the original pipe and i want the brightness to be controlled by how close the ball is to each instance. This is what i have so far...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, one way is to send the location and scale of the controller object to the material and compute the distance between the locations of the pipes and the location of the controller in the material:

[image: Node Tree]

How you use the distance is up to you.